# Add class to div after another class is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have situation like this:

```
<body class="site pace-done">
   <div class="container fade-in sppb-animated">
      bla bla bla
   </div>
</body>
```

What I want to do, is to add "fade-in sppb-animated" classes to div after "pace-done" class appear in body class. As long as "pace-done" class does not show in body class, "fade-in sppb-animated" should be removed. How to this is JS/Jquery?

I will be gratefull for any help with that.

Comment: `pace-done` what do you have in this css class?

Comment: Hi Jai ! "pace-done" is appearing in body class after all elements are loaded on page. Untile that there is class called "pace-running" . I have some animation on my page and I want them to start after "pace-done" class appear, not before. This is my page: http://manx.bdl.pl/eventart/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are putting the class on body based on some logic present on server (else this is useless and rather you should use css selectors) .

so you can do some like i have done in this example https://jsbin.com/fidolexaja/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).load()` event which fires after whole content is loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
     $('.container').addClass('fade-in sppb-animated');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function that will add the class

```
$(document).on('addClass',function(){ 
 // add class
 }
);
```

add a function that will remove the class

```
$(document).on('removeClass',function(){ 
 // remove class
 }
);
```

Now, you can throw a event to tell when to add/remove class

```
$(document).trigger('addClass'); // to addClass
$(document).trigger('removeClass'); // to removeClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked I made a script that will check if the body has an update to the class, if body has the class pace-done, it will update container and add the class fade-in. this uses setinterval and checks every 1 second

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('pace-done');
  });

  $('.remove').click(function(){
    $('body').removeClass('pace-done');
  });

  setInterval(function(){
    if ($("body").hasClass("pace-done")) {
      $('.container').addClass('fade-in');
    }else{
      $('.container').removeClass('fade-in');
    }
  },1000);
});
```

http://codepen.io/ZetCoby/pen/mVXJQK

also I suggest that you update the container div at the same time with the body, do you have some sort of js that does something to the body? or are you using some external plugins that modify the body?